# SQLite.Swift: getting null for column value where value is not null

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm running a simple query over the [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) library, selecting `id` and `start_time` from my table where the `start_time` column has a value greater than zero.

```
let query = table.where(self.columns.start_time > 0).select(self.columns.id, self.columns.start_time)
for i in try db.prepare(query) {
    print(i)
    let id = try i.get(self.columns.id)
    let start_time = try i.get(self.columns.start_time) // This throws error
}
```

Where `self.columns` is an instance of this class:

```
 private class Columns {
   let id = Expression<Int>("id")
   let start_time = Expression<Double>("start_time")
}
```

I'm getting an error complaining that there was an unexpected null value for `start_time`

> Unexpected null value for column `"start_time"`

Where the value is indeed non-null. In fact when I print out the row (variable i) this is how it looks like:

```
Row(columnNames: ["\"id\"": 0, "\"start_time\"": 1], values: [Optional(355487), Optional(1585212120000)])
```

Obviously, the value is not a null. So what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue and came to your answer. Diving into the source, I found that it basically had to do with data type you are requesting. The error is thrown here:

```
public func get<V: Value>(_ column: Expression<V>) throws -> V {
    if let value = try get(Expression<V?>(column)) {
        return value
    } else {
        throw QueryError.unexpectedNullValue(name: column.template)
    }
}
```

So basically you need to request the data in the correct  type, it won't be casted for you automatically. In your case, that would be `Int` instead of `Double`